# Azure VM to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: azure, ubuntu-16.04, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I am setting up a Ubuntu remotely, but instead of seeing the desktop version of it I been told to use this Power Shell, since I am out to office, I am trying to put some command to this Ubuntu VM as I use Chrome Remote Desktop to access it from my iPhone, can it be possible that I am not allowed to do it from my iPhone?

Comment: i suggest reworking this question. right now nothing can be salvaged from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, if we want to use Chrome Remote Desktop to connect your Azure VM, **we should configure it and open ports for Chrome Remote Desktop first**.
So I think you **can't** do that without configure chrome remote desktop first.

As a workaround, you can download other app to connect ubuntu via ssh(command line), we can search it in App store.

Comment: What I meant was I am connecting my phone to my laptop that run an Azure VM.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. we can use google chrome remote desktop to connect your Azure ubuntu VM. please refer to this link https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/flTs7Kxrdr8;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/category$3Alinux%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false     and    https://www.everything-linux-101.com/how-to/remote-control/chrome-remote-desktop-install-for-linux/

Comment: I have this one too https://askubuntu.com/q/943406/722008 I haven't tried it yet, maybe I'll drop some words after I do so. But thanks to all of you.

Comment: May I install Ubuntu 16.04 program on xfce?

Comment: @ParisKookie yes, we can use windows `mstsc` to remote this VM, we can open browser and other UI on it.

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu-desktop first, and the xrdp later than then xfce, I still couldn't see the desktop of it, then I remove Ubuntu-desktop, and still facing the same issue.

Comment: could you please show the screenshot about RDP to your ubuntu VM?

Comment: Unable to connect RDP message box saying that 3 possible reason it would not connect. I don't have the screenshot I am sorry.

Comment: we should add port 3389 to Azure VM's NSG inbound rules, and start xrdp service. please check it.

Comment: Actually I can connect before I install xfce, but that time it only show a grey screen and goes off.

Comment: @ParisKookie I see, I get that error before, we should configure it follow Azure official article,  we should install `xfce4` and `xrdp` and run `echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession`   finally, restart xrdp service with this command `service xrdp restart`, More information about install xrdp, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/use-remote-desktop).

Comment: I haven't restarted it yes, I will do soon after I reach my station.

Comment: Just back to my station, now I couldn't connect, connection refused error. I am about to send 'keep process running after ssh log out'

Comment: @ParisKookie maybe we should set process run backend,  we can use `nohup yourprocess &` to run this process backend, and keep this process in running.

Comment: @ParisKookie Can you RDP to your Ubuntu VM?

Comment: The last time I try to connect, the connection was refused.

Comment: can you telnet the VM's public IP address with port 3389?

Comment: How is that? Some more, I am outside.

Comment: Ok, use telnet xx.xx.xx.xx:3389 in windows cmd. to test the network connection and service running or not. also you can ssh to this VM, run this command `netstat -ant | grep 3389` to check the xrdp is running or not.

Comment: We never open port 23, the connection was refused.

Comment: I guess xfce won't run properly because of the 4 cores, it just too slow. Now I am testing tmux. Internet browser of xfce won't run too, even applied netsurf.

Comment: what's your mean about xfce won't run properly? when you exit the ssh, you will not able to RDP this VM?

Comment: It just too slow from RDP.

Comment: @ParisKookie Yes, too slow from RDP. if you just want to configure some application need desktop, we can use this, by default, we can use command line:)

Comment: The best thing is tmux, automate my line 'forever'

Comment: @ParisKookie thank you for your share, I will do some check for "tmux". By the way, if my answer is helpful please don't forget to accept it as an answer, thanks:)

Comment: I would try. Thanks.